# How to find the expectation of this random variable

Tags: probability-theory

Assume $\theta \sim U[0,1]$.

Fix $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and consider the following random variable:

$ g_{x}\left(\theta\right)=\begin{cases}
2-|x| & |x|\leq\theta\\
0 & \text{else}
\end{cases} $

How can I calculate the expectation of $ \mathbb{E}\left[g_{x}\left(\theta\right)\right] $?

Im not sure how to start. The answer should be

$$ \begin{cases}
1.5-2|x|+0.5x^{2} & |x|\leq1\\
0 & \text{else}
\end{cases} $$

And I'm not sure how or why.

Thanks in advance, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How about starting from the definition of $\Bbb E(X)$?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Well I tried, the problem is that the variable of the expectation is in the limits and not as an operand of an integral, so Im not sure how to do it

Comment: I think that instead of $1.5-2|x|+0.5x^2$ it should be $(2-|x|)(1-|x|)=2-3|x|+x^2$ , are you sure of the answer?

Comment: In addition to what Tortar said, are you sure an integral is necessary here? What values can the random variable $g_x(\theta)$ take on? Remember $x$ is fixed.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri I see. Thanks, this was a great explanation.

Comment: @FreeZe oops -- I took a long time to finish the answer below and realize it echoes the comments above -- oh well, it might help to see it worked out \\__('__')__/?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember what is random and what is fixed.

So for any $x,g_x(\theta)$ only takes two values: $0\text{ and }2-|x|$

Let $c_x= 2-|x|$

The probability calcs are simple:

$$P(g_x=c_x) = P(\theta \geq |x|)=\max(0,1-|x|):=p_x$$
$$\text{ and } P(g_x=0)=1-p_x$$

Therefore,

$$E[g_x] = p_xc_x + (1-p_x)(0)=p_xc_x$$

We can split into two cases:

**Case 1: $|x| \leq 1$:**
$$p_x= 1-|x| \implies E[g_x]=(2-|x|)(1-|x|)$$

**Case 2: $|x|>1$**:

$$p_x = 0 \implies ???$$

Can you take it from here -- I also don't think the given answer is correct.

Answer (score 3):

If $x>0$ the expectation is

$$(2-x)\int_x^1 d\theta =2-3x+x^2$$

If $x<0$ the expectation is

$$(2+x)\int_{-x}^1 d\theta =2+3x+x^2$$

Thus the correct expectation is

$$ \mathbb{E}\left[g_{x}\left(\theta\right)\right]=   \begin{cases}
  2-3|x|+x^{2} & |x|\leq1\\
0 & \text{else}
\end{cases} $$